# Access Content Providers in Ionic Angular

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-contentprovider, capacitor

What is the best way to access existing content provider using Ionic Angular. I am currently exploring an existing [CordovaContentProviderPlugin](https://github.com/r-cohen/cordova-ContentProviderPlugin) but I am having a problem using it in typescript after adding it in the project.

Is there any other way to access content providers perhaps using capacitor/cordova? If there is, a simple example would be very helpful ?